# Google Console: Reset in app purchases of a test account

Tags: flutter

I'm testing my Flutter app in app purchases for android.
I managed to create a test account and make a purchase, but now I'd like to reset the purchase in order to test the system further.

Tried looking around for guides by google on how to reset test account purchases, but they're as useful as wet toilet paper.

Do you guys have any insight on how I can reset/refund purchases of a tester account?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The test orders will appear in the Order Management section of Play Console, unfortunately mixed in with real orders. Find the test order you wish to reset, view the order details and click on **Refund** on the order details page. Make sure you check the **Remove entitlement** checkbox to remove the entitlement to the purchase for the app (otherwise you'll only issue a refund but the app still has rights to the purchase), then click the **Refund** button on that page.

If you are using the [Flutter in_app_purchases plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) then during testing, you can also consume the purchaseDetails on Android to remove the purchase entitlements using the Android specific platform interface:

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  final InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition androidAddition = _inAppPurchase.getPlatformAddition<InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition>(); 
  BillingResultWrapper androidResult = await androidAddition.consumePurchase(purchaseDetails);
}
```

This will remove the entitlements to the purchase, allowing you to retest your purchase logic more quickly than finding and refunding the order.